# Android Layout: Why is my button always UNDERNEATH the ListView?

Tags: android, layout

this is my current LayOut Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_above="@+id/list_of_messages"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/button_log_out"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp" />
  <ImageButton
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/button_Send"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Your message"
        android:id="@+id/input" />
    <ListView
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fab"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/list_of_messages"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is what it looks like: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAJFQ.jpg)

The LogOut button is always underneath the white part. (I just put a white background to see, how much the ListView is covering).

So - it always covers EVERYTHING in the top. Yet the "above" part with the send button and the edittext at the bottom of the layout works.

I would need to get the button to the top of the white midpart. Why on earth is it not working? I would usually switch to a linear layout, but in this particular example i cannot do that. In a lin layout I would just add weights 10 / 80 / 10. But here it doesnt work What am I doing wrong? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have set `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` for your `ListView` which makes it to be always start from top, that results in hiding of your logout button.

You should make two changes in order to get what you need.

1. Remove `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` from `ListView` and add it to logout `ImageButton`.
2. Add `android:layout_below="@+id/buttonLogOut"`to you `ListView`.
3. Remove `android:layout_below="@+id/list_of_messages"`from logout button.

Comment: hello and thanks. I cannot add this line to the listview since it already has an "above" line in the listview. or did u mean to add this line to the logout button ?

Comment: listview can contain both which means listview will be above to fab and below to logout button.

Comment: oh, so I need to add layout_BELOW instead of above? because i cannot be above twice - also it is supposed to be in the middle anyway :)

Comment: Okay thanks I thought u ment that: unfortunately this is then the output is a big error: "mono.android.DesignerException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 at mono.android.DesignerException.fromThrowable(DesignerException.java:46)" this goes on for a few lines...

Comment: oh ... it works in Android studio but you are using xamrin :p just remove `layout_above` from listview.

Comment: Yes im using xamarin. so - even with the above line removed. the same error occures. This "below" thing seems to crash everything :(

Comment: OKAY I GOT IT ! The problem was the "        android:layout_above="@+id/list_of_messages" in the LogOUt button. Appearently - you CANNOT add "above y" and "below x" when they are in relation. one is enough :) THANKS:)

Comment: ohh god you have added that also. :( Just remember design your layout in top to bottom manner is simple and easy.